# returned string from evaluateJavascript getElementById being returned with slashes and quotes

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio, webview

I am having an issue with a returned string from a `evaluateJavascript` and `getElementById` where the returned string is being formated with slashes and quotes.

For instance I have a element in my webview with the `Id` of `user_id_firebase` like so

```
<div style="display: none" id="user_id_firebase">active|12345</div>
```

So in my `getElementById` I am retrieving the `innerHTML` and what should be returned and loaded to my firebase is `active|12345`

What I am getting is this

`"\"active|20321\"`

Eventually I am splitting the string with `|` and separating those values but the initial `html` string is coming back formatted weird with slashes and quotes.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
webView.evaluateJavascript(
        "(function() { return (document.getElementById('user_id_firebase').innerHTML); })();",
        new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                String currentString = html;
                String[] separated = currentString.split("|");
                // Write a message to the database
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

                myRef.setValue(html);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue before. When we call `evaluateJavascript`, it returns the result of the script as a `JS` object and the string data is carried by a double-quot wrapped string. However, the slash characters are for escaping double-quots and you can filter the result using below snippet:

```
html = html.replaceAll("[\"]+", "");
```